# How to render conditionally with styled-components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a functional react component (hooks) called `toggle`, that has a `button` component, and when clicked, toggles the visibility of an `<styledTitle>` (`styled-components`). It looks like this:

```
const Toggle = () => {
    const styledTitle = styled.h1`
        //some styles
        //SUDO CODE: display none if toggle === true else block
    `;
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
    const handleToggle = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle)
    }
    <button onClick={handleToggle}>Click me</button>
    <styledTitle>Text</styledTitle>
}
```

I want the `styledTitle` to `display: none` if the  value of `toggle` is `true` else `display: block`

How can I do that? Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use props to add conditional styles to your styled-component.

Also define your styled component outside of your fucntional component to ensure that a single instance is created

```
const StyledTitle = styled.h1`
    display: ${props => props.visibility? 'block': 'none'}
`;

const Toggle = () => {

    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
    const handleToggle = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle)
    }

    ...
    <button onClick={handleToggle}>Click me</button>
    <StyledTitle visibility={toggle}>Text</StyledTitle>
}
```

Comment: glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Pass params

You can pass the state you made to the component

```
const Toggle = () => {
    const styledTitle = styled.h1`
        //some styles
      display: ${({toggle}) => toggle ? 'none' : 'block'};
    `;
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
    const handleToggle = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle)
    }
    <button onClick={handleToggle}>Click me</button>
    <styledTitle toggle={toggle}>Text</styledTitle>
}
```

## Optimise

Like Shubham has in his answer you should rename your variables and make the styled component a separate thing.

```
// notice the name now in pascal case, components should always be in pascalcase
const StyledTitle = styled.h1`
  display: ${({isHidden}) => toggle ? 'none' : 'block'};
`;


const Toggle = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
    const handleToggle = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle)
    }
    <button onClick={handleToggle}>Click me</button>

    // see the prop name here, isHidden, this is better than toggle as a prop
    <StyledTitle isHidden={toggle}>Text</StyledTitle>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary operator on className `<styledTitle className={toggle ? "hide" : "show"}>Text</styledTitle>`

hide and show are css class with respectively `display: none;` and `display: block`